# Cannot receive notification on iPhone 6 (iOS 9.1)

Tags: ios, swift, push-notification, iphone-6, ios9.1

I am facing a problem that I can receive notification normally on iPhone 5s and ios 8.4.1, but I cannot receive it on iPhone 6 (iOS 9.1).

Can you tell me if we need to add a new feature for iOS 9.1 or what it should be the problem?

Comment: Please provide a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Answer (score 1):

Sorry that I add this as an answer but I'm not allowed to add comments yet.

I am also using IOS 9.1 as the deployment target and tested my Notifications and they still work.

I think there are **two possible reaons** why your notification isn't working:

- Your code is not correct
- You have not allowed the app to send you notifications

If it is the second point you can change it under "Settings>Your-App>Notification>Allow Notifications".

I hope this helps.

Comment: Thank for your reply, I allowed the app to send me notification and you can find below my code :
            let settings = UIUserNotificationSettings(forTypes: UIUserNotificationType.Badge | UIUserNotificationType.Sound | UIUserNotificationType.Alert, categories: nil)       UIApplication.sharedApplication().registerUserNotificationSettings(settings)
            UIApplication.sharedApplication().registerForRemoteNotifications()

Comment: Change the seperator between the UIUserNotificationTypes from " | " to " , ". Does it work now?
Otherwise I guess your call of the notification is not correct.

Comment: you mean the didReceiveRemoteNotification or didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken

Comment: what you mean by the call of the notification?

Comment: yes, when you changed the seperator the notification registration seems to be correct, therefor I guess the call is not correct.

Comment: when I change the separation the "," did not work it give me error on syntax but when I call the notification I dont understand what you mean?

Comment: By the way, maybe it sounds crazy but have you already checked, if your notification are displayed in the notification area (slide from top of the screen down, a new window appears where you can select notifications at the top)?

Comment: Which XCode version do you use?

Comment: yes sure I checked it hehe but it did not appear, I am using xcode 6.4 but what let me crazy that the app working perfect of iphone 5 and ios 8.4

Comment: Sorry then i can't help you any further, I am using XCode 7.1. But I'm confused that ios9.1 works on xcode 6.4, I thought it only works on xcode 7.1?